# How to create Horizontal Scrollview with zoom on selected item?

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to create a horizontal scrollview like this , Please help me with this[image: This is a horizontal scrollview, whichever is selected gets zoom and rest remains small..It is an an endless scrollview.This image is fron Freecharge application]

Comment: This is a horizontal scrollview, whichever item is selected gets zoom and rest remains small..It is an an endless scrollview.This image is fromFreecharge application

Comment: please paste some code that have you tried so far.

Comment: Actually i have tried to manipulate using simple horizontal scroll views and  but want to make somethingl ike dis and not getting how to do.

Comment: I think there might be some library available for dis but not finding

Comment: I don't think you need library for simple things. Try googling around and help yourself.

Comment: Tried Googling a lot but havent found.

Comment: @ZilSanghvi If you've solved your problem take a look to my answer please maybe you can help me out :) [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219942/horitzontalscrollview-or-carrousel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way is to use coverflow/crousal libraries for this

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/830

https://github.com/mrleolink/SimpleInfiniteCarousel

https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow

Comment: I took reference from dis too : http://androidpreetsingh.blogspot.in/2014/12/hello-guys-hope-you-all-doing-well.html

Comment: This is the best and easiest I have seen. Try it: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider#advanced-usage